# How can we Re-Generated sequencial user id in autogenerated column in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can we re-generate sequential user id in autogenerated column in SQL Server?

I have a database in which `Emp_id` is an autogenerated column. I have deleted so many data so that `Emp_id` comes in un-sequence order i.e.

```
12
14
21
22
23
56...
```

So now I want `Emp_id` to be renumbered and turn into a sequence i.e.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6.....
```

Comment: If you need the numbers to be sequential, without gaps, you're probably using the wrong tool for the job. Is this an actual requirement, or just an aesthetic desire for neatness?

Comment: Yes, Its a need of my client. Can we get simple row count one by one by SQL Query.

Answer (score 0):

When that column is a `INT IDENTITY` in SQL Server, you **cannot** update the values contained in the table already.

If those values have been "auto-generated" some other way, then you could do something like this:

```
;WITH RegeneratedValues AS
(
   SELECT 
      Emp_ID,
      NewID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Emp_ID)
   FROM
      dbo.YourTable
)
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Emp_ID = regen.NewID
FROM RegeneratedValues regen
WHERE dbo.YourTable.Emp_ID = regen.Emp_ID
```

The CTE (Common Table Expression) selects the "old" `Emp_ID` values and generates new consecutive numbers order by that `Emp_ID` column using the `ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function. The `UPDATE` statement then takes those two values and updates your table based on those - assigning the new, re-generated, consecutive, gap-less numbers to `Emp_ID`